# How do I choose the geotransformation used at SpatialReference.org?

Tags: coordinate-system

Each [page at SpatialReference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/mgi-austria-gk-east/) has a UI that updates coordinates as you pan/zoom around a small map control.  Behind the scenes, it is performing a geotransformation.  I looked, but don't see a way to choose which geotransformation to use.

*Is there a way to choose the geotransformation, or at least display which one is being used?*

[image]

I'd like to be able to choose from a pick-list similar to the way I can in Arcmap's geotransformation dialog.

[image: Arcmap's geotransformation dialog].

Comment: Note, It looks like it's using EPSG::1618, MGI to WGS 84 (3). Source says OpenLayers which uses Proj4js. Since it's embedded on the page, I don't know how you'd intercept it. Similar at http://epsg.io.

Comment: Thanks @mkennedy  Would be great to see someone write a web app similar to spatialreference.org that leverages [Find Transformations](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Find_Transformations/02r3000002m0000000/) to populate a picklist in a UI, before doing the projection.

Comment: We keep talking about doing a point converter (geometry service has a very simple one), but...there's always other work to do.

Comment: How does PostGIS do this?

Comment: @DPSSpatial - that's a good question.

Comment: re: PostGIS - [ST_Transform](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) doc says it's using PROJ.4, you can check the proj4text value within the spatial_ref_sys table, particularly if grid files aren't being used properly.